# android play one sound at a time

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am stumped on this and I have referenced so many other posts. I'm not asking for anyone to complete my code but simply to point out where I'm going wrong and steer me into the right direction. I want to play an audio file when I click a image button but have it stop when another image button is clicked. The problem I'm having is if I press all the image buttons they will all play audio at the same time.

```
package com.application.cats.catsshapecolorapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;


public class ColorPage extends AppCompatActivity {


Context context = this;
MediaPlayer mpPurple,mpBlue,mpRed,mpGreen,mpYellow,mpPink;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_color_page);

    mpPurple = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.purpleaudiotest);
    ImageButton purpleB = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.purpleButton);
    purpleB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                if (mpPurple.isPlaying()) {
                    mpPurple.stop();
                    mpPurple.release();
                    mpPurple = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.purpleaudiotest);
                } mpPurple.start();
            } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    });

    mpBlue = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.blueaudiotest);
    ImageButton blueB = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.blueButton);
    blueB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                if (mpBlue.isPlaying()) {
                    mpBlue.stop();
                    mpBlue.release();
                    mpBlue = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.blueaudiotest);
                } mpBlue.start();
            } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    });

    mpRed = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.redaudiotest);
    ImageButton redB = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.redButton);
    redB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                if (mpRed.isPlaying()) {
                    mpRed.stop();
                    mpRed.release();
                    mpRed = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.redaudiotest);
                } mpRed.start();
            } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    });

    mpGreen = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.greenaudiotest);
    ImageButton greenB = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.greenButton);
    greenB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                if (mpGreen.isPlaying()) {
                    mpGreen.stop();
                    mpGreen.release();
                    mpGreen = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.greenaudiotest);
                } mpGreen.start();
            } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    });

    mpYellow = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.yellowaudiotest);
    ImageButton yellowB = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.yellowButton);
    yellowB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                if (mpYellow.isPlaying()) {
                    mpYellow.stop();
                    mpYellow.release();
                    mpYellow = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.yellowaudiotest);
                } mpYellow.start();
            } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    });

    mpPink = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.pinkaudiotest);
    ImageButton pinkB = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pinkButton);
    pinkB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                if (mpPink.isPlaying()) {
                    mpPink.stop();
                    mpPink.release();
                    mpPink = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.pinkaudiotest);
                } mpPink.start();
            } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    });

}
```

update: now the problem is the pinkaudiotest is always the first audio file to play no matter what image button I click. I have to click a second time to hear the correct audio file.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new MediaPlayer instance every click. Simply use a single one.

```
  if (media.isPlaying()) {
                    media.stop();
                    media.release();
                    media= MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.purpleaudiotest);
                } media.start();
```

Comment: Yours seems to do the trick but it has caused the pinkaudiotest to play first no matter what image button I press first. I have to press purple twice to get it to say purple because the first time it says pink, this also occurs with any color besides pink.

Comment: @DavidRodriguez, I haven't used MediaPlayer in a while but if I rememeber correctly it takes time for it to prepare and start playing (though, it might be a different problem). If those are short sounds I would suggest using the SoundPool for that.